Tkinter frame/page switching but all of the frames were shown and overridden
I'm new to tkinter so I've been looking a lot to find a way to code frames/page switcher in Tkinter as efficient as possible. And also another reason because I need to find an answer now so might as well post it here.
I encountered an issue where all of the frames would show at once and wouldn't hide themselves, therefore making the frame/page switching function unswitchable. How do I rewrite the code so that the frame/page switching function can work properly again?
I tried many ways to find out how to do this and now I am finally able to do it without any errors. I checked through the code and I haven't seem to find anything wrong with it that causes the switching function to not work properly. I hope for answers that solves my problem, thanks!
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.resizable(height=1000, width=700)
        self.title("a")
        root = tk.Frame(self)
        root.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frames = {}
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (main_menuHauptmenu, lange):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame #self.frames[page_name] = Frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(main_menuHauptmenu)
    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
class main_menuHauptmenu(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        hm_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Select Conversion Mode", font=("Times New Roman", 20))
        hm_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        unit_modus = ttk.Combobox(self)
        unit_modus['values'] = ('Länge')
        unit_modus['state'] = 'readonly'
        unit_modus.grid(row=0, column=1)
        if unit_modus.get() == "Länge":
            lambda:controller.show_frame(lange)          
class lange(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        gl_frame = tk.Frame()
        gl_frame.pack()
        of = tk.Frame(gl_frame)
        of.pack(side='left')
        pf = tk.Frame(gl_frame)
        pf.pack(side='left')
        rf = tk.Frame(gl_frame)
        rf.pack(side='right')
        qf = tk.Frame(gl_frame)
        qf.pack(side='right')
        ##  Label
        Masseneinheit1 = tk.Label(of, text="Masseneinheit 1:").pack(side='top', anchor='nw')
        Masseneinheit2 = tk.Label(of, text="Masseneinheit 2:").pack(side='top', anchor='nw')
        ## Entry
        def validate_entry(text):
            if (
                all(char in "0123456789.-" for char in text) and
                "-" not in text[1:] and
                text.count(".") <= 1):
                       return True
            else:
                return False
        nz = tk.StringVar()
        ez = tk.Entry(pf, textvariable=nz, validate='key')
        ez['validatecommand'] = (ez.register(validate_entry), '%P')
        ez.pack(side='top')
        resl = tk.StringVar()
        res = tk.Label(pf, textvariable=resl)
        res.pack(side='top')
        ## Combobox 
        enm = tk.StringVar()
        em = ttk.Combobox(qf, textvariable=enm)
        em['values'] = ('km', 'hm', 'dam', 'm', 'dm', 'cm', 'mm', 'in', 'ft', 'yd', 'mi')
        em['state'] = 'readonly'
        em.pack(side='top', anchor='ne')
        em.current()
        znm = tk.StringVar()
        zm = ttk.Combobox(qf, textvariable=znm)
        zm['values'] = ('mm', 'cm', 'dm', 'm', 'dam', 'hm', 'km', 'mi', 'yd', 'ft', 'in')
        zm['state'] = 'readonly'
        zm.pack(side='top', anchor='ne')
        zm.current()
        #Funktion
        a = int()
        km = 1000
        hm = 100
        dam = 10
        m = 1
        dm = 0.1
        cm = 0.01
        mm = 0.001
        inch = 0.0254
        ft = 0.3048
        yd = 0.9144
        mi = 1609.34
        er = int()
        zw = int()
        combobox_er = str()
        combobox_zw = str()
        def conv():   
            # Zahl
            er = km if em.get() == "km" else hm if em.get() == "hm" else m if em.get()\
                == "m" else dam if em.get() == "dam" else \
                dm if em.get() == "dm" else cm if em.get() == "cm" else \
                    mm if em.get() == "mm" else inch if em.get() == "in" else \
                        ft if em.get() == "ft" else yd if em.get() == "yd" else \
                            mi               
            zw = km if zm.get() == "km" else hm if zm.get() == "hm" else \
                m if zm.get() == "m" else dam if zm.get() == "dam" else \
                dm if zm.get() == "dm" else cm if zm.get() == "cm" else \
                    mm if zm.get() == "mm" else inch if zm.get() == "in" else \
                        ft if zm.get() == "ft" else yd if zm.get() == "yd" else \
                            mi
            # Combobox
            combobox_er = "km" if em.get() == "km" else "hm" if em.get() == "hm" \
                else "dam" if em.get() == "dam" else "m" if em.get() == "m" else \
                "dm" if em.get() == "dm" else "cm" if em.get() == "cm" else \
                    "mm" if em.get() == "mm" else "in" if em.get() == "in" else \
                        "ft" if em.get() == "ft" else "yd" if em.get() == "yd" else \
                            "mi"               
            combobox_zw = "km" if zm.get() == "km" else "hm" if zm.get() == "hm" else \
                "dam" if zm.get() == "dam" else "m" if zm.get() == "m" else \
                "dm" if zm.get() == "dm" else "cm" if zm.get() == "cm" else \
                    "mm" if zm.get() == "mm" else "in" if zm.get() == "in" else \
                        "ft" if zm.get() == "ft" else "yd" if zm.get() == "yd" else \
                            "mi"
            if em.get() == combobox_er and zm.get() == combobox_zw:
                a = float(nz.get()) * er / zw
                resl.set(format(a, '.16f').rstrip('0').rstrip('.'))
            else:
                pass
        button = tk.Button(rf, text="Umrechnen!", command=conv)
        button.pack(side='top', anchor='ne')

app = main()
app.mainloop()






This isn't related to the frame issue, but you may want to check out the match statement as an alternative to those crazy-long if-else chains. I'd also recommend taking a look at the Python style guide - following a style guide ultimately makes your code easier for others to read and can save you time when debugging later because your code becomes more manageable.

You forgot to specify the parent of gl_frame, so it will be created inside the root window instead of lange.
Specify the parent when creating gl_frame:
class lange(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        gl_frame = tk.Frame(self)   # pass self as parent
        ...

